# Выделение номера машины в тексте. Python, re

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Нужно номер машины заменить на слово "номермашины" (именно слитно). С этим проблем нет, я написал для этого код, но есть ситуации, когда он находит номер машины там, где его нет. Например, строки для входа:

```py
['хомута 150 мм 100', 'стяжки х 150 мм 50 шт', 'а 150 ку 99', 'номер а150ку99']
```

Мой код обрабатывает так:

```py
['хомут номермашины ', 'стяжки  номермашины  шт', ' номермашины ', 'номер  номермашины ']
```

А нужно так:

```py
['хомута 150 мм 100', 'стяжки х 150 мм 50 шт', ' номермашины ', 'номер  номермашины ']
```

В первом случае мой код принял последнюю букву слова "хомута" за первую букву номера машины. Во втором случае понятно, что это не номер, а просто единицы измерения товара (мм, шт); вместо "шт" бывает "м". А в третьем и четвертом случаях все верно.

Мой код регулярного выражения:

```py
re.sub('[авекмнорстух]{1}\ {0,}[0-9]{3}\ {0,}[авекмнорстух]{2}\ {0,}[0-9]{2,3}', ' номермашины ', text)
```

Comment: неочевидно что `х 150 мм 50` не номер авто

Comment: Как вариант добавить параметр `re.UNICODE` и `\b` как границу слова. так же `\ [0,]` можно заменить на `\ *`. По поводу стяжек, нужно понимать за что зацепиться что бы их исключить

Comment: /(?<!\w)[авекмнорстух]\s*\d{3}\s*[авекмнорстух]{2}\s*\d{2,3}$/ - так вышло

Comment: @Виктор да, но если это сплошной текст, то ^ и $ не применить

Comment: @splash58 Дык у автора уже разобрано по строкам :)

Comment: @splash58 после х 150 мм 50 есть "шт", поэтому не номер

Comment: @ipatev_nn как добавить  re.UNICODE? В каком месте в регулярном выражении?

Comment: @Makss123 https://regex101.com/r/aiWQaV/1

Comment: @Виктор не сработал код, номер машины не определяет

Comment: @splash58 все, спасибо, заработало

Comment: но могут же быть не только штуки, вам еще настраивать и настраивать этот код

Comment: `re.UNICODE` вам тут не нужен (в Python 3 он используется по умолчанию). Не заморачивайтесь.